Number of distinct real roots of $1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+.....\frac{x^{2025}}{2025!}=0$


Find the number of distinct real roots of $$P(x)=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+.....\frac{x^{2025}}{2025!}=0$$


My try:
I tried to find critical points by setting $P'(x)=0$. So we get
$$1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+.....\frac{x^{2024}}{2024!}=0$$
But again not sure, how to find whether the above equation has any zeros?

After taking $2024$ derivatives, what function is left?  Does the original function remind you of any specific series, perhaps $e^x$?

That is an odd degree McLaurin polynomial of the exponential. It can be proven (see this) that it has exactly one real root.

$P'(x)$ doesn't have any roots. If it did, then there would be a point $x$ where $P''(x) = 0$ and $P'(x) < 0$. But $P'(x) \ge P''(x)$ for all $x$. Now, if $P'(x)$ doesn't have any roots, then either $P'(x) > 0$ for all $x$, or $P'(x) < 0$ for all $x$. In either case, $P(x)$ is strictly monotone. Therefore, $P(x)$ has exactly one real root.

Possibly a duplicate of this question. At least the answer can be found there.

@JasonSwanson A monotonically increasing function doesn't automatically have a real root, does it? $f(x) = e^x$ has no root and is increasing.

@EricSnyder No, but this is an odd degree polynomial, so it tends to $\infty$ on one side of the $x$-axis, and to $-\infty$ on the other.
